# String between special characters

Tags: regex

How can I extract the following string in-between these special characters when it can also present itself without the last 2 bracket sets?

```
[Sometext Noworry (Sometext)] I need this string (This string is ok too) [Dontwantit] [Dontwantiteither]
```

or

```
[Sometext Noworry (Sometext)](whitespace here sometimes)I need this string (This string is ok too)
```

or

```
(Notneeded) [Sometext Noworry (Sometext)] I need this string (This string is ok too)
```

or

```
[Sometext Noworry (Sometext)](whitespace here sometimes)I need this string (This string is ok too) {Notwanted}
```

Struggling with positive lookbehinds, but so far I've gotten:

```
/[^\[\]]+(?=\[|$)/g
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Do you want to delete unwanted text or capture wanted text? What are the expected results for all these examples?